# Javascript Array of Objects- Assignment of values while using rest operator

Tags: javascript

I had been trying to find elements in original array which aren't present in subset - like y1 and y2 in code. With y1, i got expected b:"b". But with y2, I was believing since it is empty, entire original array will be assigned to rest1. But response is different from expected. Could you please help understand how?

```
var x =[{a: "a"}, {b: "b"}];
var y1 = [{a: "a"}];

var [y1,...rest] = x;
console.log(rest); // returns [{b:"b"}]

var y2=[];
var [y2,...rest1] = x;
console.log(rest1); //returns [{b:"b"}]
console.log(y2); // returns {a: "a"}
```

Comment: You might want to use a `Set` with a difference function implemented, like in [implementing basic set operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#implementing_basic_set_operations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `var [y1,...rest] = x;` or `var [y2,...rest1] = x;`, you're assigning the first value of `x` to `y1` or `y2`.

Whatever the original values of `y1` and `y2` were, they have no bearing on that result.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for more information on destructuring assignments.

Comment: Oh no. I understand that now. First example was an illusion that y1 was set as same as its defined value. It actually had no impact.